# Can't provide future education date on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, dates

I am currently a student, and although I have checked the "I am currently a student" box on my Careers 2.0 profile and have included "[in progress]" as suggested by the tooltip, I also need to be able to accurately specify the intended timeframe of my course of study.

I can't leave the end year blank (it gives a "Missing end year" error), and I can't set an end year in the future (since they're not available in the dropdown), so my only other reasonable option is to select the current year (since it's *technically* the latest year in which I've been a student *so far*) and remember to change it later on.  I'm then stuck explaining in the freeform "achievements" section that that year doesn't actually mean anything, *à la*:

```
Master of Science, Computer Science [in progress], University of Pittsburgh
August 2011 - April 2013
NOTE: Expected graduation is actually December 2014.
```

This seems less than desirable.  Can we be permitted to set reasonable future end dates (within ~7–10 years, like LinkedIn or Facebook) for the end dates of education items?  Perhaps even ~1 year in the future for start dates, too, in the case that people are accepted to a program they are yet to formally begin.

**Related:** I can't seem to change the months on education items, only the years.  Not sure why, but now one of my "end months" is stuck on something that's likely to be wrong, independent of the year.

Comment: Most resume systems allow "Present" as an end date.  You can't do that in Careers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Current" is a checkbox option for each item in the Experience section, which has the desired affect (disabling the end date boxes, since presumably you don't know when your employment might end).  However, "I am currently a student" is a checkbox for the entire Education section (not each item), and it appears to have no effect on how the dates are handled.

Comment: I just added a "School of Hard Knocks" education that has no end date.  I didn't get a "Missing end year" error.  (But adding future, expected graduation dates seems like a good idea anyway.)

Comment: @JonEricson Maybe I'm getting the "Missing end year" error because I have an end month listed? Still doesn't help the underlying problem of being able to specify **neither** a future end date nor an end date of "present". Either would be acceptable, but I think the case can be made that listing specific future dates has its purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we be permitted to set reasonable future end dates (within ~7–10
>   years, like LinkedIn or Facebook) for the end dates of education
>   items? Perhaps even ~1 year in the future for start dates, too, in the
>   case that people are accepted to a program they are yet to formally
>   begin.

Yes! That's a great suggestion and we've made that exact change. You can now select +1 year for the start year and +7 years for the end year in the education section.

> Related: I can't seem to change the months on education items, only
>   the years. Not sure why, but now one of my "end months" is stuck on
>   something that's likely to be wrong, independent of the year.

We've gotten rid of months in the education section a while ago (they really didn't seem to matter that much to anyone). They still showed up on profiles which had month+year entered before we made the change. Since it's not possible to change the months anymore, it doesn't make sense to display them on the profile either, so we fixed that as well and got rid of them altogether.

Comment: **Thanks!**  I'm amazed no one thought of it sooner!  And although I'm a little disappointed to see the months gone from the Education section (I'd personally still like the option to include them), it's _far_ better to have them gone entirely than to have had them continue their confusing half-existence.